# How to combine different layers in r ggplot with 2 different datasets - one for map & other for geom_area?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot with `geom_area()`, `geom_line()` in it. Now I would like to add a **country map background** in the **plot** and for same I am trying to use: `map_data()` & `geom_ploygon()` but it's giving error, probably because one's **xaxis** is on date scale & other's is longitude.

Error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Here is my code & plot without map:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(scales)
library(tidytext)
```

data:

```
file_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/ts_all_long3.csv"

ts_all_long <- read.csv(url(file_url))
```

Step 1:

```
confirm_col = "#32a4ba"
death_col = "#f08080"
Country_selected = c("India")

scaleFactor = max(ts_all_long %>% 
                    filter(Country.Region %in% Country_selected) %>% 
                    pull(Confirmed_daily)) / 
              max(ts_all_long %>% 
                    filter(Country.Region %in% Country_selected) %>% 
                    pull(Death_daily))


ts_all_long %>%
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("India") ) %>%

ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Confirmed_daily), fill = confirm_col, alpha = .7) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Death_daily * scaleFactor), col = death_col, 
            size = 0.8, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Daily Cases", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "Daily Deaths"),
                     labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(25000,95000), lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(ymd("2020-07-08"),ymd("2020-09-10"),
                            ymd("2021-03-15"),ymd("2021-04-03")), 
             lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2020-08-10"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3, 
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2months+") +
  
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2021-03-18"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3,
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2weeks+") +
  
  geom_text(
          label=glue("1st wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2020-07-30"), y= 75000,
          size = 4, color = confirm_col
            ) +
  geom_text(
          label=glue("2nd wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2021-03-18"), y= 75000,
          size = 4, color = confirm_col
            ) +
  
  
  theme_excel_new() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    plot.title = element_markdown(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 14),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank()
  ) + 
  
  labs(title = glue("<i>{Country_selected}</i>: Daily Cases to jump to 1 lac in 1st & 2nd wave, as of: {max(ts_all_long$date)}"),
       
       # subtitle = "Cases to jump from 25,000 to 95,000 in first & second wave",
       caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics
       Created by: ViSa")
```

[image]

Step 2: Code & image for map:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("world", region = "India"),
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill="lightgray", colour = "white")
```

[image]

Step 3: When I try to combine code for above 2 steps I get an error:

```
confirm_col = "#32a4ba"
death_col = "#f08080"
Country_selected = c("India")

scaleFactor = max(ts_all_long %>% 
                    filter(Country.Region %in% Country_selected) %>% 
                    pull(Confirmed_daily)) / 
              max(ts_all_long %>% 
                    filter(Country.Region %in% Country_selected) %>% 
                    pull(Death_daily))


ts_all_long %>%
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("India") ) %>%

ggplot() +
  
  # added country map here from step2
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("world", region = "India"),
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill="lightgray", colour = "white") +

  # usual plot of step1
  geom_area(aes(x = date, y = Confirmed_daily), fill = confirm_col, alpha = .7) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = Death_daily * scaleFactor), col = death_col, 
            size = 0.8, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Daily Cases", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "Daily Deaths"),
                     labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(25000,95000), lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(ymd("2020-07-08"),ymd("2020-09-10"),
                            ymd("2021-03-15"),ymd("2021-04-03")), 
             lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2020-08-10"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3, 
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2months+") +
  
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2021-03-18"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3,
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2weeks+") +
  
  geom_text(
          label=glue("1st wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2020-07-30"), y= 75000,
          size = 4, color = confirm_col
            ) +
  geom_text(
          label=glue("2nd wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2021-03-18"), y= 75000,
          size = 4, color = confirm_col
            ) +
  
  
  theme_excel_new() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    plot.title = element_markdown(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 14),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank()
  ) + 
  
  labs(title = glue("<i>{Country_selected}</i>: Daily Cases to jump to 1 lac in 1st & 2nd wave, as of: {max(ts_all_long$date)}"),
       
       # subtitle = "Cases to jump from 25,000 to 95,000 in first & second wave",
       caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics
       Created by: ViSa")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add the map as a background image to your plot which could be done via e.g. the `ggimage` package like so:

```r
library(ggimage)

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("world", region = "India"),
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill="lightgray", colour = "white") +
  theme_void()
ggsave("map.png")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image

ggbackground(p, "map.png")
```

[image]

**p**:

```
d <- ts_all_long %>%
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("India")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Confirmed_daily), fill = confirm_col, alpha = .7) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Death_daily * scaleFactor), col = death_col, 
            size = 0.8, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Daily Cases", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name = "Daily Deaths"),
                     labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(25000,95000), lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(ymd("2020-07-08"),ymd("2020-09-10"),
                            ymd("2021-03-15"),ymd("2021-04-03")), 
             lty = 2, col = "grey50") +
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2020-08-10"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3, 
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2months+") +
  
  annotate("text", x = ymd("2021-03-18"), y = 96000, col = death_col, size = 3,
           label = "25k to 95k in \n~2weeks+") +
  
  geom_text(
    label=glue("1st wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2020-07-30"), y= 75000,
    size = 4, color = confirm_col
  ) +
  geom_text(
    label=glue("2nd wave"), angle = 90, x=ymd("2021-03-18"), y= 75000,
    size = 4, color = confirm_col
  ) +
  theme_excel_new() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color=confirm_col),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color=death_col),
    plot.title = element_markdown(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 14),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank()
  ) + 
  labs(title = glue("<i>{Country_selected}</i>: Daily Cases to jump to 1 lac in 1st & 2nd wave, as of: {max(ts_all_long$date)}"),
       # subtitle = "Cases to jump from 25,000 to 95,000 in first & second wave",
       caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics
       Created by: ViSa")
```

Comment: thanks @stefan, I guess this is the only way to get this done and its working well. Appreciate your help & will be careful from next time in changing the date column to date format in SO reproduce code example !!